# Mostrar una fecha que ingreso en JText desde Java y que se almacene en SQL

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, date

No estaria logrando que pueda ingresar una fecha de nacimiento en mi programa para llenar una ficha de un cliente y que se guarde en la base de datos de sql desde xampp, lo pude hacer como string pero obviamente no toma las barras "/". Quiero directamente cargar la fecha y que se guarde en SQL. Mi codigo donde cargo los datos son los siguientes:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {             
    try {                   
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            java.sql.Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tienda","root","");                         
            String nombre = textField_1.getText();
            int precio = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText());
            String descripcion = textArea.getText();

            JTextField textField_3 = new JTextField();
            SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                 
            String query = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre,precio,descripcion) values('"+nombre+"','"+precio+"','"+descripcion+"')";

            Statement s = conexion.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate(query);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nombre agregado");

        } catch (Exception e) {                 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
            // TODO: handle exception
        }           
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

el campo en la tabla podrías dejarlo como DATETIME, y en Java:

SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de'  MMMM 'del' yyyy",new Locale("ES"));
java.util.Date fechaActual = new Date();
String fecha = formato.format(fechaActual).